# DeepL using significant energy

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications, intel, energy

Why does the DeepL desktop application consume a lot of energy? Even more than Chrome. How can I diagnose it?

MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2019 (Intel chip)
[image: DeepL using significant energy]

Comment: I quickly installed the application on my M1 Mini, it burned a lot of CPU time just by sitting in the menu bar and waiting for things to do. Seems to be a general problem which needs to be addressed by the company.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside. My feedback has been submitted to the company.